# The SendGrid can not be used on my App with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I have been trying to add the SendGrid starter-free in my App with the ruby on rails, however, every time I failed to do it.
The message below are popped up.

"Item could not be created:
An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to
create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status -
banned."

How can I fix this matter?

I am beginner and not native English speaker.
Thank you in advance for your kind response.

Kind regards,

Comment: Hi, did you follow instruction for ruby? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/

Comment: Appreciate your kind suggestion! Sorry but I could not figure out even though I checked the git hub. I am studying Rails Tutorial, so code could be correct. May something trouble in Heroku...

Comment: `User status - banned` implies that your heroku account is banned by sendgrid.